# Блэк-метал или блек-метал?

Tags: орфография, заимствования

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: "блэк-метал" или "блек-метал"?
В орфографическом словаре есть "блек-джек" и "блек-рот", но и "блэкаут".
На что рекомендуете полагаться? Допустимы ли оба варианта?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: P.S. Эти рекомендации соответствуют и издательской практике: если вы проведете поиск исключительно по книгам, то там доминируют "блэк-метал" (термин приписан по происхождению группе Venom) и "Блэк Саббат".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как орфографические словари не фиксируют слово "блэк-метал", то авторитетных рекомендаций тут дать нельзя.
Я попытался найти что-то на эту тему.
Попалась такая статья:

[Э или е. Викичтение](https://culture.wikireading.ru/67874)

Но в ней ничего путного я не нашёл.
Куда более интересной оказалась вот такая:

[Инструкция по передаче английских географических названий. СССР. 1975 г.](https://culture.wikireading.ru/67874)
В Параграфе 23 сказано, что "Э" пишется только в начале слова и после гласных (кроме i).
В параграфе 24 сказано, что в "Е" пишется в остальных случаях.

Думаю, мы вполне можем применить тот же принцип и к другим словам английского языка.
Однако...
Я бы оставил решающее слово за частотностью употребления. И здесь преимущество на стороне "Э": Джо Блэк, блэкаут, Олл Блэкс, Лукас Блэк, Блэк Бист, Блэк Гидра и, собственно, блэк-метал тоже практически везде пишется именно через "Э".
В противовес "Э" "Е" при передаче слова "black" пишется нечасто: блек-ро́т (вики пишет об устаревшем варианте блэ́крот), блек-джек.

В сложные моменты неоднозначности стоит полагаться на корпус русского языка. А там, к счастью, хватает примеров:

> говорит автор открытия Кармен Блэк. От «Блэк Лейбла»? Или от всего

> вместе? Marduk ― 2015 Frontschwein ― блэк.  в невадской пустыне

> Блэк-Рок
> Правда, позднее выяснилось, что Блэк был зачат не от нобелевской спермы

и внезапно:

> и пристраивался играть с моими соседями в «Блэк Джек» ставят деньги на

> рулетку или блэк-джек

303 вхождения для "блэк".

> А что по "блек"? 81 вхождение. примеры:

> Стёпа Маяковский, чей стих

> "Блек энд уайт" Элли и Чарли Блек,

> поклоннику Блек Саббат конец очень

> понравился Это малышка «Блек эрроу»

и вдруг опять:

> «Блек-джек» ― это «очко»

Стало быть, даже одно и то же слово можно писать по-разному.
К сожалению, "блэк-метал" и "блек-метал" в нацкорпусе не встречаются.
Я бы сказал, что в этой теме есть недосказанность, и предложил бы не изобретать велосипед, а смело использовать "Э", полагаясь на частотность употребления варианта "блэк-метал".